# Eliminar duplicados de un Array de objetos, pero solo de un mismo tipo

Tags: javascript, jquery, array, object

Para un proyecto en el que trabajo tengo un Array de objetos con el cual actualizamos un filtro y necesito que los de un tipo concreto solo puede haber un valor de cada, pero no encuentro la manera de poder filtrar solo por un tipo de dato (filtro: "kilometros"). Muchas gracias y disculpad si es demasiado básica la consulta estoy desde hace muy poco con JavaScript.

```js
[
  {"name": "España","id": 109,"filtro": "pais"},
  {"name": "Portugal","id": 209,"filtro": "pais"},
  {"name": "Diesel","id": 101,"filtro": "combustible"},
  {"name": "Gasolina","id": 201,"filtro": "combustible"},
  {"name": "25000 Kms - 150000 Kms","id": "25000,150000","filtro": "kilometros"}
]  

  // Filtro para eliminar rangos duplicados
  function FilterRangeTypes(data) {
    var $f = $filter;
    var op = [],
    map = {},it,item;

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      it = data[i];
      item = map[it.filtro];
      
      //console.log(item);
      if (item) {
        item.filtro;
      } else {
        map[it.filtro] = item = {
          name: it.name,
          id: it.id,
          filtro: it.filtro
        };
        op.push(item);          
      }
    }
    return FiltrosComprador = op;
    // End for(data) 
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: A ver si lo he entendido: quieres quedarte con sólo un objeto para cada posible valor del campo filtro, lo que en el ejemplo dado sería sólo eliminar un elemento (el que tiene como nombre Gasolina). ¿Es eso?

Comment: Hola @PabloLozano la idea es que de ese tipo solo pueda haber uno, realmente tengo varios tipos de los que solo puede haber uno pero para el ejemplo solo puse ese.

Comment: por ejemplo 
```
[
  {"name": "España","id": 109,"filtro": "pais"},
  {"name": "Portugal","id": 209,"filtro": "pais"},
  {"name": "Diesel","id": 101,"filtro": "combustible"},
  {"name": "Gasolina","id": 201,"filtro": "combustible"},
  {"name": "25000 Kms - 150000 Kms","id": "25000,150000","filtro": "kilometros"},
  {"name": "25000 Kms - 150000 Kms","id": "25000,150000","filtro": "kilometros"},
  {"name": "2012","id": "2012","filtro": "edad"},
  {"name": "2012","id": "2012","filtro": "edad"}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurre usar el método [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) junto con un acumulador: es sencillo de implementar y (creo) de entender:

```js
const array = [
 { "name": "España", "id": 109, "filtro": "pais" },
 { "name": "Portugal", "id": 209, "filtro": "pais" },
 { "name": "Diesel", "id": 101, "filtro": "combustible" },
 { "name": "Gasolina", "id": 201, "filtro": "combustible" },
 { "name": "25000 Kms - 150000 Kms", "id": "25000,150000", "filtro": "kilometros" },
 { "name": "25000 Kms - 150000 Kms", "id": "25000,150000", "filtro": "kilometros" }, 
  { "name": "2012", "id": "2012", "filtro": "edad" }
]


function filtrarRepetidos(array,campo, valoresCampo) {
  const valores=[];
  return array.filter((elem) => {
    if (valoresCampo.includes(elem[campo]) && valores.includes(elem[campo])) { //si ya se añadió, no pasa el filtro
      return false;
    }
    valores.push(elem[campo]); //nuevo valor, se añade a la lista
    return true;
  });
}

console.log(filtrarRepetidos(array,'filtro',['combustible','kilometros']));
```

Comment: El problema del ejemplo que comentas es el mismo que ya tengo que filtra todos los elementos del array y no solo aquellos que sea de un tipo concreto en este caso (filtro: kilometros, filtro:edad)
Son estos dos campos los que debo filtrar el resto deben quedar tal cual.

Comment: Ok, ahora lo arreglo, no me había quedado claro esa parte

Comment: Funciona perfecto! Muchas gracias!!!
Y ya se que con esto abuso de tu voluntad :(
Pero de que forma se puede hacer para borrar el anterior y mantener el ultimo que se agregue de ese tipo?

Comment: Puedes dar la vuelta al array: `filtrarRepetidos(array.reverse() ' filtro', ...);`